NUnit constraint in TestCase
I want to test a function Foo(string input) that may return null or not. If the input is "A" it should return null. If it is "B", it should return not null. I was thinking about the following:
[TestCase("A", Is.Null)]
[TestCase("B", Is.Not.Null)]
public void TestFoo(string input, Constraint expectedContraint) 
{
   var result = Foo(input);

   Assert.That(result, expectedConstraint);
}

This fails because the constraints are not a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type. I could fix it simply with a TestCaseSource, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.
One option:
[TestCase("A", true)]
[TestCase("B", false)]
public void TestFoo(string input, bool shouldBeNull) 
{
   var expectedConstraint = shouldBeNull ? Is.Null : Is.Not.Null;
   var result = Foo(input);

   Assert.That(result, expectedConstraint);
}

but in that case it adds logic to the test, which I'd like to avoid.
Moreover, I have the feeling that Assert.That(result, expectedConstraint) has not the best readability.
A variant to fix this would be
   if (shouldBeNull) {
      Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
   } else {
      Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
   }

but again, this adds some logic to the tests.
A way to avoid the logic and improve the readability would be to split the test in two separate tests. In that case, though, if the test is quite complex to setup (and that's why I want to avoid adding logic), I'd be duplicating too much code.
I think that in most of the cases any of these solutions is ok and there is not much difference, but I'd like to know if there is an interesting NUnit feature I miss or there is some good practice I could apply to write the tests cleaner. Thanks!

Why not simply have two separate distinct TestCase-Methods? "I'd be duplicating too much code" - why is that? You can factor out setup. If the current example doesn't sufficiently display the actual complexity of your tests, consider a better example ...

Can you simply be more explicit and not input a constrain but exact values and test for equality? Typically you should know better then Is.Not.Null and get an exact value to test for. If not you presumably have an incomplete unit test at hand and work with dependencies you don't control but should.

"Typically you should know better then Is.Not.Null" - should you? Maybe the set of inputs [a..b] is expected to yield random but non-null results? Or for this test it's the only concern they are non-null but the exact value is more or less irrelevant? That's totally legit.

@Fildor string emphasis on typically here. In your example i would assume the source of "randomness" can be mocked away to get a specific repeatable result. The likelihood of implementing some sort of randomness without a source for the random part that can be mocked away is possible but unlikely. Hence the word typically.

@Ralf Fair enough. Maybe. Could also end up "over testing". At least I don't think it's getting OP anywhere. The example is obviously simplified. Maybe too much - so, hard to judge the actual need.

I would consider this somewhat opinionated but here's what we are doing and why:
(We are using xUnit, though. But that doesn't matter, here.)
[TestCase("B")]
public void FooShouldReturnNotNull(string input) 
{
   SomeComplexSetup();
   var result = Foo(input);

   Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
}

[TestCase("A")]
public void FooShouldReturnNull(string input) 
{
   SomeComplexSetup();
   var result = Foo(input);

   Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
}

private void SomeComplexSetup()
{
  // Just a stupid dummy for showcase
}

For each assertion-option we have a separate method. So we can separate test data sources into "classes" of which each one is expected to result the respective outcome. That makes it crystal clear which input(s) is supposed to do what without the need for logic inside the test code (which could have bugs, too and we do not want to test tests, right?).
Possible DRY-violation can be avoided by factoring out shared code and calling it.
But we'd not break a leg over that. A little repetition would be accepted. If you need to change the tests, you'd need to do so causiously, anyway.
Heads up: If your TestCases run concurrently you obviously need to pay attention when factoring out shared setup to be threadsafe / able to be run concurrently for all cases.

Further Info: NUnit - like other Testing Frameworks - has a rich set of Test Setup and -Teardown features, which you can read in their documentation : SetUp and TearDown

I would also do the same! I would specify roughly two tests: WhenInputIsLikeSomething_ReturnsNotNull and WhenInputIsLikeSomethingElse_ReturnsNull and for each would provide collection of "right params" the provide consistent result that i would assert.

Just to add to this code, we can directly Assert.That(Foo("B"), Is.Null).

@prabhaat For one, I didn't want to stray too far from the original. And then, maybe there is also [TestCase("C")] that is just about to be added ... :) - The example is a simplifaction, after all.

In this simple case, you can do the following in NUnit:
[TestCase("A", ExpectedResult = true]
[TestCase("B", ExpectedResult = false]
public void TestFoo(string input) 
{
   return Foo(input) == null;
}

or, if you know the expected value for "B",
[TestCase("A", ExpectedResult = null]
[TestCase("B", ExpectedResult = "Something"]
public string TestFoo(string input) 
{
   return Foo(input);
}

I assumed that Foo returns a string, if not you can adjust accordingly.
